# w2ui grid, editable field with list and remote data source

Tags: w2ui

I have W2UI grid with list field:

```
{field: 'serial', caption: 'Serial', size: '100px', editable: { type: 'list', items: serials, showAll: true, match: 'contains' }, sortable: true, selected: {id: 1},
    render: function (record, index, col_index) {
         var html = this.getCellValue(index, col_index);
         return html.text || '';
    }
},
```

And I want to use data from server for this list cells. But if I tried use 'url' parametr my list is shown only when i typed some charatcer (it's a filter). And if I set 'items' parameter - everething fine, full list open when I clicked on field. Is there a way to use remote source with list field and without filter by typing characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an url parameter and don't want to filter the result, you should set minLength: 0, so the whole list will be shown immediately.